# xx counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions package$Class is a non-static inner class, and JAXB can't handle those

Tags: java

Hello I have Java Bean like blow and I need to create xml file with it , but when run the program error say :

```
mehritco.ir.megnatis.ejb.nlp.aiml.Aiml$Template$Random is a non-static inner class, and JAXB can't handle those.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at mehritco.ir.megnatis.ejb.nlp.aiml.Aiml$Template$Random
        at public mehritco.ir.megnatis.ejb.nlp.aiml.Aiml$Template$Random mehritco.ir.megnatis.ejb.nlp.aiml.Aiml$Template.getRandom()
        at mehritco.ir.megnatis.ejb.nlp.aiml.Aiml$Template
        at public mehritco.ir.megnatis.ejb.nlp.aiml.Aiml$Template mehritco.ir.megnatis.ejb.nlp.aiml.Aiml$Category.getTemplate()
        at mehritco.ir.megnatis.ejb.nlp.aiml.Aiml$Category
        at public java.util.List mehritco.ir.megnatis.ejb.nlp.aiml.Aiml.getCategories()
        at mehritco.ir.megnatis.ejb.nlp.aiml.Aiml

    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:106)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:471)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:303)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:139)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1156)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:165)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:288)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:277)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:400)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:721)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:662)
```

The JavaBean :

```
package mehritco.ir.megnatis.ejb.nlp.aiml;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "aiml")
public class Aiml {
    List<Category> categories = new ArrayList<Category>();
    
    public List<Category> getCategories() {
        return categories;
    }
    @XmlElement
    public void setCategories(List<Category> categories) {
        this.categories = categories;
    }

    
    @XmlRootElement(name = "category")
    public class Category<T>{
        Pattern pattern ;
        Template<T> template ;
        public Pattern getPattern() {
            return pattern;
        }
        @XmlElement
        public void setPattern(Pattern pattern) {
            this.pattern = pattern;
        }
        public Template getTemplate() {
            return template;
        }
        @XmlElement
        public void setTemplate(Template template) {
            this.template = template;
        }
        
        
        
        
    }
    @XmlRootElement(name = "pattern")
    public class Pattern{
        String pattern;

        public String getPattern() {
            return pattern;
        }
        @XmlElement
        public void setPattern(String pattern) {
            this.pattern = pattern;
        }
        
    }
    @XmlRootElement(name = "template")
    public class Template<T>{
        Random random;
        String template;

        public Random getRandom() {
            return random;
        }

        public void setRandom(Random random) {
            this.random = random;
        }


        public String getTemplate() {
            return template;
        }

        public void setTemplate(String template) {
            this.template = template;
        }




        @XmlRootElement(name = "random")
        public class Random {
            List<String> li = new ArrayList<String>();

            public List<String> getLi() {
                return li;
            }
            @XmlElement(name = "li")
            public void setLi(List<String> li) {
                this.li = li;
            }

        }
        
        
        
    }
    
    
    
    
}
```

The Main Method :

```
        Aiml aiml = new Aiml();

        List<Aiml.Category> listCategory = new ArrayList<Aiml.Category>();
        Aiml.Category category =   aiml.new Category();
        
        Aiml.Pattern pattern = aiml.new Pattern();
        pattern.setPattern("Hello");
        category.setPattern(pattern);
        
        Aiml.Template<Aiml.Template.Random> template = aiml.new Template<Aiml.Template.Random>();
        Aiml.Template.Random random = template.new Random();
        List<String> list = random.getLi();
        list.add("hi");
        list.add("hello");
        random.setLi(list);
        template.setRandom(random);
        category.setTemplate(template);
        
        listCategory.add(category);
        aiml.setCategories(listCategory);
        
        

          try {

            File file = new File("D:\\TestFile\\file.xml");
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Aiml.class);
            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

            // output pretty printed
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(aiml, file);
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(aiml, System.out);

          } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
```

I need create java class that create aiml object for me to save , read the object that I'm created but in this type class Created it can't be done , some what's my problem in using JAXB?
[the xml format I'm need to create is here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AIML) and some other that can be happen like :

```
<category>
    <pattern>ONCE I *</pattern>
    <template>
        <random>
            <li>Go on.</li>
            <li>Can you be more specific?</li>
            <li>I did not know that.</li>
            <li>Are you telling the truth?</li>
            <li>I don't know what that means.</li>
            <li>Try to tell me that another way.</li>
            <li>What is it?</li>
        </random>
    </template>
</category>
```

For now I need to know what is the Exception here and what must to do

Comment: You have declared Random inside Template, shouldn’t it be in the same scope as Template instead? That is directly inside Aiml. Or not declared as a XmlRootElement?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thanks for response , Can you explain more ?

Comment: No not really, that is just what I concluded from reading the error message and looking at your code. But if I were you I would research if I needed another annotation or simply try to move the class and see if that works.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson , I do that but with split class error come with : javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.SAXException2: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class mehritco.ir.megnatis.ejb.nlp.aiml.Random nor any of its super class is known to this context.
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class mehritco.ir.megnatis.ejb.nlp.aiml.Random nor any of its super class is known to this context.]

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I think problem is the List because Using String in random work and I can see the output